# htaccess redirect to subdomain via SSL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My domain is https://webkust.be, now i trying made a subdomain https://labs.webkust.be

I used Direct Admin and SSL (Let's Encrypt)

So in the **/public_html/**, set this in htaccess:

```
## REDIRECT TO HTTPS 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$
https://www.webkust.be/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Adding the website in **/private_html/**
This works perfect for **webkust.be**

But now i try adding a new subdomain on the same hosting **https://labs.webkust.be**
This doesn't work.
Is there a way redirecting the subdomain to **https://**?

Comment: you're missing the  `> ` to close the  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c ` it has to be  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It should work for subdomains as well. [Docs](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess#force-https)

Comment: Hi moonflare, thank you for your answer. I try it tomorrow.

Comment: The htaccess snippets on Github are very useful. Thank you.

Comment: Hello,
I try it, but doesn't work.
I place the code in /private_html/.htaccess, but with no luck.
There shows a red https:// with a red line across https://

Comment: Hey Tuxy,

Sorry for the delay. I think there might be something regarding your SSL Certificate. The reason might be that your cert is not a wildcard one. Please read this answer and see if that helps: https://serverfault.com/a/566433

Comment: No problem moonflare. I read the post and i think indeed the certificate has no wildcard option.